# How to add a list of tags to a Flask > WTForms > Jinja2 form?

Tags: flask, tags, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I'm building a web form and trying to allow users to autocomplete a list of tags (much like StackOverflow uses here) without reloading the form, which can then be submitted en masse with a click of the Submit button.

The engine is a simple python function that appends an empty list of tags but I can't seem to integrate the function correctly.

I suspect the issue is that the page is reloading when I click the 'Add' button but I'm not sure and even less sure how to prevent it.

Thanks for your help. Code below:

HTML:

```
<form class="centered" action="" method="post" role="form" autocomplete=off>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <p>{{ form.toppings(type="text", list="topps", placeholder="| e.g. cheese, tomato, etc.", **{"onchange":"addTag(tag,tags)"}) }}
    <datalist id="topps">
        {% for top in topps %}
        <option value={{ top }}>
        {% endfor %}
    </datalist>
    <span>{{ form.add(**{"onchange":"addTag(tag,tags)"}) }}</span></p><br>
    <p>
        {% for tag in tags %}
        <span>{{ tag }} {{ form.remove(value="x",**{"onchange":"tags.pop(0)"}) }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
    </p><br>
    <p>{{ form.submit(type="submit", value="Submit") }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.reset(type="reset", value="Reset", **{"onchange":"tags=[]"}) }}</p>
</form>
```

FLASK PYTHON:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = ToppingsForm()
    topps = Topps.query.all()
    tag = ''
    tags = []
    def addTag(tag,tags):
        if tag not in tags:
            tags.append(tag)
        else:
            tag = ''
    addTag = addTag(tag,tags)
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', form=form, topps=topps, tag=tag, 
tags=tags, addTag=addTag)
```

FORMS.py:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class ToppingsForm(FlaskForm):
    toppings = StringField('Toppings', validators=[DataRequired()])
    agree = BooleanField('Agree', validators=[DataRequired()])
    add = SubmitField('Add')
    remove = SubmitField('x')
    reset = SubmitField('Reset')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Comment: According to my understanding, you have a bunch of tag options and you want to select a multiple of them, right? Can you also post your wtfform code?

Comment: In your post I see that you have the , "{{ form.add(**{"onchange":"addTag(tag,tags)"}) }}" . Could you also provide the javascript addTag function here

Comment: @AkibRhast The addTag function is embedded in the Flask index() function. I've written it in Python. Is that the issue - it should be in JavaScript?

Comment: @JackPutter While you can certainly pass a python function via jinja templates, I see you are using "onchange" , which if I am not mistaken might be an issue

Comment: @JackPutter Of the top of my head, I am not sure what the error is, but if you provide a [MRE] . I can look further into it. In your case, just provide the ToppingForm() and the topps list you get from "Topps.query.all()"

Comment: @AkibRhast Is there an alternative to "onchange" ? I've tried to find a code playground for it but none of them seem to accept Python with all of the dependencies.

Comment: I have edited my above comment in regards to what you need to add, just add those to your original post @JackPutter

Comment: @AkibRhast Thanks, I've just updated the question with forms.py. The topps query is just a database request which works fine so it's definitely not that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214830/discussion-between-akib-rhast-and-jack-putter).

Answer (score 1):

So I believe what you are looking for is "SelectMultipleField" provided by wtfform.
You want something like this:

```
class ToppingsForm(FlaskForm):
    #toppings = StringField('Toppings', validators=[DataRequired()])
    toppings = SelectMultipleField('Toppings', choices=[],validators=[DataRequired()])
    #agree = BooleanField('Agree', validators=[DataRequired()])
    #add = SubmitField('Add')
    #remove = SubmitField('x')
    #reset = SubmitField('Reset')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

---

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = ToppingsForm()
    choices = [("cheese","cheese"), ("tomato","tomato"),("anchovies","anchovies"),("anchovies","mozarella")]
    form.toppings.choices = choices #you would change this to something like this[(c.id, c.name) for c in Topps.query.all()]

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print(form.toppings.data)
        return "success"
    return render_template('base.html', title='Home', form=form)
```

---

Look into how to use SelectMultipleFields for more example

Comment: Ah I see, changing it to a selection list doesn't quite work for my purposes unfortunately. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: @JackPutter Owh, my bad I did not realize that there was a restriction on selection list usage. I was under the impression that you were struggling to get multiple option selected. May I know why the restriction, and how you would want it?. If you could clarify in your original posts the restrictions you have, why you have those restrictions and so on. I am sure someone else would be able to assist you in greater detail!